# how to determine a slow javascript client or server?

Tags: angularjs, performance, server, client, firewall

I've been developing angular/hapi portal on a removable usb disk which I can take to different clients' sites.  Recently, I noticed on my home computer delay is up to 600ms.  At client's site and my portal (moonCFO.com), there is no delay -- up to 70ms.  When there is a delay, I can't move to the next button.

I've tried to trace through batarang but don't quite understand how to read the bottle neck.  I've tried to remove firewall.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe fiddler has a throttle feature which you can use to throttle all requests accessing a specific host:port

Comment: great suggestion on fiddler...thanks

Comment: used fiddler to turn off win 10 auto update and speed is back to normal...thanks a million